# How to implement this kind of IO-based loop using higher order functions?

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

I have some code like the following which updates `state` based on random `sample`s read from disk:

```
myloop 0 state = return state
myloop n state = do
  sample <- getRandomSampleFromFile
  myloop (n - 1) (process state sample)
```

How can this be written idiomatically using higher order functions to avoid the explicit function and recursion (and preferably without pulling in a massive library)?

---

Clarification: I cannot just do a `replicateM n getRandomSampleFromFile` because I have a huge number of samples I need to process and it's infeasible to read all samples into memory first.

Comment: I'm not sure that replicateM would have to read all sample in memory. I might be wrong.

Comment: @mb14 It of course will!! `replicateM` like `sequence`, `traverse` and `mapM` only make sense where you are treating lists like arrays. You might as well use a real array type from e.g. `vector` As soon as you see those words, think "Maybe a streaming library?". On long lists they will *always* accumulate the list and cause a space leak. This is why we have the streaming libraries. (It is possible e.g. to specialize `replicateM` & company to IO and then use something like lazy io, see http://twanvl.nl/blog/haskell/unsafe-sequence )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you understand how it works, `foldr` is surprisingly versatile when working in a monad:

```
myloop n = foldr w return [1..n] where
    w _ k state = do
        sample <- getRandomSampleFromFile
        k (process state sample)
```

Note:

```
w _ k state = getRandomSampleFromFile >>= k . process state
```

so

```
myloop n = foldr (\ _ k state -> getRandomSampleFromFile >>= k . process state) return [1..n]
```

The reason this works is that `foldr`'s definition:

```
foldr f z [] = z
foldr f z (x:xn) = f x (foldr f z xn)
```

in the `:` case, puts the recursive call into a thunk and *tail calls* `f`, passing it that thunk.  You don't necessarily think about that, because in many of the simple folds `f` is strict in its second argument anyway (so the recursive call is effectively performed before the body of `f` is entered anyway), but `foldr` actually hands `f` control immediately, and lets it decide when (if ever) to perform the recursive call.  So almost any recursive structure can be re-written as a `foldr`.

Comment: This if "`foldlM` as `foldr`", not "` foldlM'` as `foldr`", so to speak, and can be observed to leak space. Try `main = myloop (+) (readLn::IO Int) 1000000 0 >>= print` with enough lines of text.

Comment: This can be cured with use of `$!`

Answer (score 2):

This should provide a hint:

```
> import Control.Monad
> foldM (\n x -> print (n,x) >> return (n+x)) 0 [10,20,30]
(0,10)
(10,20)
(30,30)
60
```

In your case, `n` is an index-state pair (or only the state, if the index is not needed in the computation), and `x` is the sample at hand.

Answer (score 1):

From

```
myloop 0 state = return state
myloop n state = do
  sample <- getRandomSampleFromFile
  myloop (n - 1) (process state sample)
```

split reading data / process data

```
xs <- mapM (const getRandomSampleFromFile) [1..n]
```

take `n` samples now, simply fold

```
foldl process state xs
```

you can use applicative syntax

```
myloop n state = foldl process state <$> mapM (const getRandomSampleFromFile) [1..n]
```

or (thk2 @andrás-kovács)

```
myloop n state = foldl process state <$> replicateM m getRandomSampleFromFile
```

if you wish break the reading process (or process data while reading) then, you must enter into monad

```
myloop n state = foldM acc state [1..n]
    where acc s _ | breakProcess s = return s
                  | otherwise      = process s <$> getRandomSampleFromFile
```

but folding will not stop then, your initial aproach (after all) looks better.

```
myloop n state | breakProcess state = return state
               | otherwise          = do
                                        x <- getRandomSampleFromFile
                                        myloop (n - 1) (process state x)
```

Any way, I encourage use [`conduit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes), [`pipes`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes), ... if you are looking for some streaming processing.

(By the way, note that your `getRandomSampleFromFile` function may have hardcoded configuration, it's not good)

Comment: I didn't indicate this in the original question, but wouldn't this mean I have to read *all* the random samples off of disk first? That would not be feasible for my use case.

Comment: `mapM (const x) [1..n] = replicateM n x`

Answer (score 0):

I want to offer my solution as this has been bending my brain for some time.

What we need is a function with the following signature:

```
iteratively :: Monad m => (a -> m a) -> a -> [m a]
```

and it should hold that `iteratively m i` repeatedly applies the monadic action `m` on successive outputs of the previous actions[1]. The reason that the output must be an array of monadic actions is that we're only interested in the `n`-th monadic actions that represents the one with `n` successive applications.

The implementation I arrived at is this:

```
iteratively step init = iterate (>>= step) (return init)
```

Now, the action `m` that has been repeated `n` times with initail value `init` is - and thus analogous to your `myloop`:

```
repeatedly :: Monad m => (a -> m a) -> a -> Int -> m a
repeatedly step init n = iteratively step init !! n
```

[1]: `m` here represents the monadic action that returns the argument to the next action - what you call `sample`. It can be implemented in terms of `getRandomSampleFromFile` and `process` thus:

```
process <$> getRandomSampleFromFile
```